# How do I replace a <li> element in HTML with something different using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an existing list of items, along with info on those lists that are displayed when the user clicks on the list item. I have to create a button (which I have) that when clicked, shows a different list along with new info. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="races" id="5k">
                <h3>5k/10 Events</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li class="sprint">Mini Sprint</li>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="info">10/30/17<br/>Memorial Park<br/>Appleton</li>
                        </ul>
                    <li class="iron">Iron Horse</li>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="info">11/06/17<br/>Bay Beach Park<br/>Green Bay</li>
                        </ul>
                    <li class="twilight">Twilight Trail</li>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="info">11/13/17<br/>River's Edge Park<br/>Wrightstown</li>
                        </ul>
                </ul>
</div><!--  End of '5k' div-->
<nav>
    <button id="futureEvents">Future Events</button>
</nav>
```

And here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var v = f;

    $("button#futureEvents").click(function(){
        if (v == false){
            $(".sprint").replaceWith("<li class='snowball'>Snowball Sprint</li>");

            v = true;
        }//end if
    });//end future events button
});//end document ready
```

I have to throw this in as well, to display the info when the user clicks on a list item:

```
$("li").click(function() {
$(this).next().children().toggle();

});
```

Can someone please help me? I am not understanding why the replace with method doesn't work at all. It should at least replace the text when I click the button...Thank you!

Comment: Your markup doesn't contain the button which triggers the `replaceWith`. You need to add the relevant markup so that issue can be replicated.

Comment: sorry, i forgot it. Updated to include the button now. Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked in the Developer Console for errors? The `var v = f` looks pretty suspicious. What is `f` here? Does that exist from some library already invoked before your shared code starts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues with your code

- initialize `v` to `false` rather than `f`
- You need to toggle by using `nextUntil`

**DEMO**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var v = false;
  $("button#futureEvents").click(function() {
    if (v == false) {
      $(".sprint").replaceWith("<li class='snowball'>Snowball Sprint</li>");
      v = true;
    }
  });
});

$("li").click(function() {
  $(this).nextUntil( "li" ).toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="races" id="5k">
  <h3>5k/10 Events</h3>
  <ul>
    <li class="sprint">Mini Sprint</li>
    <ul>
      <li class="info">10/30/17<br/>Memorial Park<br/>Appleton</li>
    </ul>
    <li class="iron">Iron Horse</li>
    <ul>
      <li class="info">11/06/17<br/>Bay Beach Park<br/>Green Bay</li>
    </ul>
    <li class="twilight">Twilight Trail</li>
    <ul>
      <li class="info">11/13/17<br/>River's Edge Park<br/>Wrightstown</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
<nav>
  <button id="futureEvents">Future Events</button>
</nav>
```

Comment: yep, it was as simple as replacing f with false! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Update your code with following snippet..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var v = false;
    $("button#futureEvents").click(function(){
        if (v == false){
            $(".sprint").replaceWith("<li class='snowball'>Snowball Sprint</li>");
            v = true;
        }//end if
    });//end future events button
});//end document ready

$("li").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="races" id="5k">
                <h3>5k/10 Events</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li class="sprint">Mini Sprint
                        <ul>
                            <li class="info">10/30/17<br/>Memorial Park<br/>Appleton</li>
                        </ul></li>
                    <li class="iron">Iron Horse
                        <ul>
                            <li class="info">11/06/17<br/>Bay Beach Park<br/>Green Bay</li>
                        </ul></li>
                    <li class="twilight">Twilight Trail
                        <ul>
                            <li class="info">11/13/17<br/>River's Edge Park<br/>Wrightstown</li>
                        </ul></li>
                </ul>
</div><!--  End of '5k' div-->
```